# When to use blank parameters in Java?

Tags: java

My question may be really simple but I just want to know when you would use blank parameters.

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
```

See at the end of the code there are blank parameters. In which situations would you use those blank parameters?

Comment: Get a good Java book Sameer. That should answer this :)

Comment: @sameer54321 This may be help you [Creating Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Comment: You mean *no arg constructor* rather than *empty parameters*. You should read the documentation of the class and decide if you're initializing it with the default values or if you want/need to provide specific parameters. It depends if the API allows you to do that, of course.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: lack of code formatting hid the type parameters. Indeed not a duplicate in that scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd use them when you don't need to give the constructor or method any data. In the case of your `ArrayList` it's to make an empty array with a default capacity of 10 elements (OpenJDK implementation).

As an abstract example, I can tell you to `eat()` but I don't care what you eat, so I don't tell you what to eat. (in the case of a method)

Or I can make a `new Bookshelf()` but I don't have any books, so I don't tell it anything, I just need an empty bookshelf. (in the case of a no-args constructor)